# If Quotient ring is complete local is the ring complete local?

Tags: ring-theory, commutative-algebra, local-rings

Let R be a Noetherian commutative ring and N the nil radical.

Given R/N is a complete local ring, is R also a complete local ring?

If R had two maximal ideal m and n then m+N and n+N are maximal ideals in R/N and that gives a contradiction.

How do I solve the completeness part?

What happens if I drop the Noetherian criteria?

Comment: $R=\bigcup_{n\ge 1} k[x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n]/(x_1^1,x_2^2,\ldots,x_n^n)$ is not Noetherian, $N = \sum_{n=1}^\infty x_n R$, $R/N=k$ is a field thus complete local, $N$ is the only maximal ideal of $R$, 

and $\sum_{n=2}^\infty x_n^{n-1}$ converges in $\varprojlim R/N^j$ but it is not in $R$.

Comment: Thanks. How do I prove for Noetherian?

Comment: No idea. If $R$ is Noetherian of characteristic $p$ then $N$ is finitely generated by nilpotent elements, $N^{p^k}=0$ so that $R$ is a $R^{p^k} \cong (R/N)^{p^k}$ algebra